# Adding next and previous buttons to a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to have my listview display 5 rows and when the next button is pressed it shows the next 5 and when the previous is clicked it shows the previous 5. For some reason, it is not working it logs of the app so if anyone can tell me where I've gone wrong that would be very helpful. Thank you

InventoryStatus class:

```
public class InventoryStatus extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDB;
int position = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_status);


    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewStock);
    Button btNext = findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    Button btPrevious = findViewById(R.id.buttonPrevious);

    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getAllData();

    if(data.getCount() == 0 ){
        Toast.makeText(InventoryStatus.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        while (data.moveToNext()){
            theList.add("Name: " + data.getString(0) + " Quantity: " + data.getString(1) + " Type: " + data.getString(2));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            
            for(int i = position; i < position + 5; i++){
                theList.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
    btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            position += 5;
        }
    });
    btPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            position -= 5;
        }
    });

 
}

}
```

Activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".InventoryStatus">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewStock"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="359dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewInventoryStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/inventory_status"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.549"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.967" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/previous"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.967" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample project that I wrote (just comment Your main and add this, it will work with Your layout)

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InventoryStatus extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ArrayList<String> fullList; // list which keeps all data from DB
    private ArrayList<String> displayedList; // list which is currently displayed in ListView
    private int currentPos = 0; // position in `fullList`
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewStock);
        Button btNext = findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        Button btPrevious = findViewById(R.id.buttonPrevious);

        fullList = new ArrayList<>();
        displayedList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Load data from db to fullList (I am not using db to show example)

        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
        {
            fullList.add("Name " + i);
        }

        if (fullList.size() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else // fullList isn't empty show first 5 items in ListView
        {
            setDisplayListPosition();
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }

        btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) // change current position and refresh ListView
            {
                currentPos += 5;
                if (currentPos > fullList.size()) currentPos -= 5;
                else
                    setDisplayListPosition();
            }
        });

        btPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() // change current position and refresh ListView
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                currentPos -= 5;
                if (currentPos < 0) currentPos = 0;
                else
                    setDisplayListPosition();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setDisplayListPosition() // helper function which refresh ListView based on `currentPos`
    {
        displayedList.clear(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 5 && i + currentPos < fullList.size(); i++)
        {
            displayedList.add(fullList.get(currentPos + i)); // ad 5 items from finalList to displayedList
        } 

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                               displayedList
        );

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I add my database to fullList though? I tried fullList. add("Name" + i + "Quantity" + i + "Type" + i); but that doesnt work

Comment: If this answered your question correctly, then accept it as an answer and ask a new question.